# Yodlee, TimeWithBank details from ItemSummary

Tags: yodlee

Is it possible to get information about how long user work with particular bank using Yodlee service. Currently we get ItemSummary response but it is a bit hard to determine which field is best fit for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the online banking sites don't provide any such information. If account open date is provided by them then Yodlee may scrape it. You can find it under accountOpenDate tag under bankData of itemSummary. But this data is rarely available and the tag may not appear if data is not present with Yodlee.